# Pandas can't remove column name on the index column

Tags: python, pandas

**EDIT:** Question heavily edited to create a reproducible example.

I have loaded a dataframe where the rows and column were swapped, so as a first step I've transposed it:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], 
                   "B": ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 
                   "C": ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']})
```

[image]

```py
df = df.transpose()
```

[image]

Then the columns' names were set using a row from the dataframe:

```py
# take the first row of df and set its values as col names
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)  # remove the first row
```

[image]

This caused my index column to be called "A", but I want to remove/rename it.

Setting the index name to `None` did nothing, the index name renamed unchanged.:

```py
df.index.name = None
```

while setting it as a string creates an index name but doesn't remove the first one (that remains on top)

```py
df.index.name = "Foo"
```

[image]

I tough this was a multi-index problem but `df.index.names` is empty.

**Question**: if it's not the index column name, what does "A" represent and how to remove/rename it?

**EDIT:** I was able to remove it by following the [BEN_YO answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655489/1191416) but I'm not sure why exactly.

Comment: It's hard to get an accurate picture of the situation from a... picture. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC you are right, I've made a big edit in order to add clarity and code.

Comment: Can you do the same with the output you share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, you can try assign it back ,also it is `column` name not `index` name

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis="columns")
```

Comment: This did work indeed. I've edited the question to be more clear. Based on this edit would explain why this work, and what my `A` column name represent if not the index column?

Comment: @Leonardo _Based on this edit would explain why this work, and what my A column name represent if not the index column?_ Does my answer help clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

> Question: if it's not the index column name, what does "A" represent and how to remove/rename it?

My terminology might be off, but I believe it's the name of the column axis.

Take a look at this tweaked version of your example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                   "B": ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                   "C": ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']})

print(df, end='\n\n')

df = df.transpose()
print(df, end='\n\n')

# take the first row of df and set its values as col names
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
print(df, end='\n\n')

df = df.iloc[1:]
print(df, end='\n\n')

print(f'index: {df.index}\ncolumns: {df.columns}')
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0  A1  B1  C1
1  A2  B2  C2
2  A3  B3  C3

    0   1   2
A  A1  A2  A3
B  B1  B2  B3
C  C1  C2  C3

A  A1  A2  A3
A  A1  A2  A3
B  B1  B2  B3
C  C1  C2  C3

A  A1  A2  A3
B  B1  B2  B3
C  C1  C2  C3

index: Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
columns: Index(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], dtype='object', name='A')
```